# PostgreSQL Error: set-valued function called in context that connot accept a set

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to convert a T-SQL procedure to PL/PGSQL procedure,
When i run my function i have this following error: "set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set".
without the "RETURN QUERY" i will have an error "query has no destination for result data" that why i added it
Find below the error message and my function
[image]

```
create or replace function public.UP_GetCumulPerformancesParPortefeuille(strMatricule VARCHAR(20), strDevise varchar(3), dateDebut DATE) returns setof record 
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN

DECLARE NO_PTF_V INT;
        DT_CRS_V DATE;
        PC_PRF_V FLOAT;
        ResultF FLOAT = 0;
        PreviousResult FLOAT = 0;
        PreviousCPA INT = 0;
        Performances public.performancestb;
        PerfCumul public.perfcumultb;
        curseur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT NO_PTF, DT_CRS, SUM(PC_PRF * MT_DEM) 
            FROM (
                SELECT D.NO_PTF, P.DT_CRS, P.PC_PRF
                    , D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
                FROM public.TB_Demande D
                    INNER JOIN
                    public.performancestb      P ON D.ID_CPA =  P.ID_CPA
                                        AND D.MC_UTL =  strMatricule
            ) Q
            WHERE DT_CRS >= dateDebut
            GROUP BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS
            ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS;
          
-- Chargement de l'historique des performances
--
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.performancestb (ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF)
SELECT ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF FROM public.UF_GetHistoriquePerformances(strDevise);

OPEN curseur;  

FETCH NEXT FROM curseur   
INTO NO_PTF_V, DT_CRS_V, PC_PRF_V; 

WHILE(found) loop
        
    IF PreviousCPA = 0 OR PreviousCPA <> NO_PTF_V then
   
        PreviousResult := 0;
        PreviousCPA := NO_PTF_V;
    end if;
    ResultF := PreviousResult + PC_PRF_V * (PreviousResult + 100);
    PreviousResult := ResultF;

    INSERT INTO public.perfcumultb (NO_PTF, DT_CRS, MT_PRF)
    VALUES (NO_PTF_V, DT_CRS_V, ResultF);
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM curseur   
    INTO NO_PTF_V, DT_CRS_V, PC_PRF_V; 
end loop;
CLOSE curseur;  

Return query(SELECT NO_PTF, DT_CRS, MT_PRF, MT_PRF + 100 as MT_PRF_BSE_100
     , CASE WHEN DT_CRS = FIRST_VALUE(DT_CRS) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF,DT_CRS)
            THEN 0
            ELSE ((100 + MT_PRF) / (100 + LAG(MT_PRF, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS))) - 1
       END 
       * 100 AS MT_VOL
     , CASE WHEN MT_PRF = FIRST_VALUE(MT_PRF) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS)
             AND MT_PRF < 0
            THEN MT_PRF
            ELSE ((MT_PRF + 100) / MAX(MT_PRF + 100) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS 
                                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 1 )
                    * 100
       END AS MT_MAX_DDO
  FROM public.perfcumultb);

end;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

General advise - when you come from MS SQL world, forget all and start with reading [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) - it has only 50 pages related to PLpgSQL. Almost everything is different in Postgres.

Postgres doesn't supports unbound queries - every query should to have some target - or you can use `PERFORM` statement, that throw result of query. If you want to push query's result to output, you should to use `RETURN QUERY` statement.

Syntax of `RETURN QUERY` is `RETURN QUERY query`. Parenthesis there are useless. But in your example is visible MS SQL pattern that is not used in Postgres. There (MSSQL) you fill temp table, and on the end you read this table. Porting this pattern to Postgres is antipattern - instead filling aux table, you should to use `RETURN NEXT` and return row immediately. Maybe you need it (I don't know because you use window functions in final query, but there will be significant overhead).

Instead manual fetching from cursor and manipulation with cursor, you can use `FOR IN cursor` statement.

Your function returns undefined recordset, because you used `returns setof record`. Then you should to call this function with special syntax - `SELECT * FROM fx(args) as (colname typename, ...)`. Better to use `OUT` arguments, and then you don't need to specify result structure in query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(IN nrows int, OUT a int, OUT b int)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT i, i+1 FROM generate_series(1,nrows) g(i);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM foo(3);
┌───┬───┐
│ a │ b │
╞═══╪═══╡
│ 1 │ 2 │
│ 2 │ 3 │
│ 3 │ 4 │
└───┴───┘
(3 rows)
```

Please, start by reading documentation - T-SQL is really different language and environment, and moving to PLpgSQL is not intuitive.

Comment: sorry, when I write function like that I do not have "a" colum name instead of "function_name": CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fnc_list_title(out a text)
  RETURNS SETOF text 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    ----
 RETURN query select n from unnest(array[
  'Project Manager',
  'Director'
 ]) n(a)
 ;
  
END;
$function$
;

Comment: @May'Habit  `select fnc_list_title()` is working without any problem in my postgres

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution by creating an intermediate table as return type instead of using setof record as return type.
Find below the solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.up_getcumulperformancesparportefeuille(strmatricule character varying, strdevise character varying, datedebut date) returns setof resultfinal
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN 

DECLARE NO_PTF_V INT;
        DT_CRS_V DATE;
        PC_PRF_V FLOAT;
        ResultF FLOAT = 0;
        PreviousResult FLOAT = 0;
        PreviousCPA INT = 0;
        Performances public.performancestb;
        PerfCumul public.perfcumultb;
        curseur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT NO_PTF, DT_CRS, SUM(PC_PRF * MT_DEM) 
            FROM (
                SELECT D.NO_PTF, P.DT_CRS, P.PC_PRF
                    , D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
                FROM public.TB_Demande D
                    INNER JOIN
                    public.performancestb      P ON D.ID_CPA =  P.ID_CPA
                                        AND D.MC_UTL =  strMatricule
            ) Q
            WHERE DT_CRS >= dateDebut
            GROUP BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS
            ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS;
          
-- Chargement de l'historique des performances
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.performancestb (ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF)
SELECT ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF FROM public.UF_GetHistoriquePerformances(strDevise);

OPEN curseur;  

FETCH NEXT FROM curseur   
INTO NO_PTF_V, DT_CRS_V, PC_PRF_V; 

WHILE(found) loop

    IF PreviousCPA = 0 OR PreviousCPA <> NO_PTF_V then
 
        PreviousResult := 0;
        PreviousCPA := NO_PTF_V;
    end if;

    ResultF := PreviousResult + PC_PRF_V * (PreviousResult + 100);
    PreviousResult := ResultF;

    INSERT INTO public.perfcumultb (NO_PTF, DT_CRS, MT_PRF)
    VALUES (NO_PTF_V, DT_CRS_V, ResultF);
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM curseur   
    INTO NO_PTF_V, DT_CRS_V, PC_PRF_V; 

end loop;
CLOSE curseur;  

return query(SELECT NO_PTF, DT_CRS, MT_PRF, MT_PRF + 100 as MT_PRF_BSE_100
     , CASE WHEN DT_CRS = FIRST_VALUE(DT_CRS) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF,DT_CRS)
            THEN 0
            ELSE ((100 + MT_PRF) / (100 + LAG(MT_PRF, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS))) - 1
       END 
       * 100 AS MT_VOL
     , CASE WHEN MT_PRF = FIRST_VALUE(MT_PRF) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS)
             AND MT_PRF < 0
            THEN MT_PRF
            ELSE ((MT_PRF + 100) / MAX(MT_PRF + 100) OVER (PARTITION BY NO_PTF ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS 
                                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 1 )
                    * 100
       END AS MT_MAX_DDO
  FROM public.perfcumultb);

end;
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: No need to create an intermediate type. Just use `returns table (...)`